# Increasing Accuracy of Synaptics Touchpad - Arch Linux

Tags: linux, touchpad

Here's my current problem with my Arch Linux installation. The touchpad is *horribly* inaccurate. And by that, I mean, I cannot click links without having to sway back and forth. I've been resorting to using my keyboard for small clicking actions. I was previously on Mint, and the touchpad was much more accurate, if not as accurate as Windows' touchpad drivers are.

I was able to hold my finger on the touchpad and it wouldn't jitter around, and I was able to select text where I wanted to.

So my all in all question is, is there at all a way to increase the accuracy of the mouse?

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed synaptics driver with pacman, problem description remind me what was hapenning to me before  driver instalation.

Comment: Are you using a desktop environment ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then when you press touchpad in left upper corner, then mouse cursor instantly goes to that corner on the screen.

Then the problem is that you did not install package `xf86-input-synaptics`.

After installation there is `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` config file. By default it might suit your needs. After package's installation you must restart xorg for synaptics driver to take effect.

Comment: It is currently installed. That was the first thing I did after installing Xorg, then I rebooted. I definitely have the package. It's just that accuracy is the big problem. I have to try to click certain things multiple times because the mouse cursor doesn't stop moving when you hold it down.